# how to add a series of numbers to an array from file?

Tags: c, arrays

In C, while reading from file,the problem is to read a set of space separated integers into an array and last integer as another entity like

```
 { 2 3 14 } 15
 { 2 3 15 16 19} 20
```

To store 2 3 14 into an array and 15 as separate variable and same with next set enclosed in brackets , which i need to store in a structure.

```
   struct dataset{
   int support;
   int s[100]; 
   }
```

and read file using

```
while( fscanf(fp,"%1d %d",dataset[i].s[k],&dataset[i].support) != EOF )
```

here the dataset[i].s[k] should read a set of integers enclosed within brackets into array.

Comment: Use `strtol()` instead of `scanf()`, can you provide a sample file? Also, don't compare `fscanf()` output to `EOF` but instead to the number of values that it has to read, if it fails to read, you will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't make us do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fscanf` looks strange...

In the line

```
fscanf(fp,"%1d %d",dataset[i].s[k],&dataset[i].support)
```

Pay attention at:

1) what `%1d` mean? (perhaps, `%d` is what you need)

2) it seams you need two `fscanf`: the first for items in `s` (this should be in the nested loop), and the second for `support`

3) I do not see what you do with '{' and '}' characters from file...